# Mysql continue handler sytax error

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I can't see what is wrong with this syntax please help! I tried to look up the syntax from here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html

```
   DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `load_dimensions`$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `load_dimensions`( )
    BEGIN

     -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
      DECLARE code CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
      DECLARE msg TEXT;
      DECLARE rows INT;
      DECLARE result varchar(300);
      -- Declare exception handler for failed insert
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN
           GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
      END;

    INSERT  dimtable(col)
    SELECT  col FROM extract;

    IF code = '00000' THEN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;
        SET result = CONCAT('succeeded, row count = ',rows);
        INSERT INTO etl_log (result)
        SELECT CONCAT('Error',state,': ',msg);
      ELSE
        SET result = CONCAT('failed, error = ',code,', message = ',msg);
        INSERT INTO etl_log (result)
        SELECT CONCAT('Error',state,': ',msg);
      END IF;

    END $$
```

Comment: If you're seeing an error message it would be very helpful if you posted that too.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;       END;' at line 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL 5.5 reference pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/condition-handling.html)

> The GET DIAGNOSTICS statement is not supported until MySQL 5.6.

Comment: thanks I just found that the mysql version we have is 5.5.35 what other statement can i use to get the error message text ?